# Parse Java .txt file and save each element in a data structure

Tags: java

I need to parse a .txt file in Java

[image]

How can I parse each element and save it in a data structure?

For example element[0] will be 480, element[3] will be 100 and so on...
I have to skip all the spaces
Here's the code I'm writing, the problem is that next shows everytime not the next token, but the next character!

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner inFile1 = null;
    try {
        inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\emiliano\\Desktop\\dataset\\RanReal480\\RanReal480_01.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s*");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println(inFile1.next());
    System.out.println(inFile1.next());
    System.out.println(inFile1.next());
    System.out.println(inFile1.next());
    System.out.println(inFile1.next());
    System.out.println(inFile1.next());

    inFile1.close();


    }
 }
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: OK, you have our blessing. Come back when you face any *specific* problem. BTW don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)).

Comment: "*element[0] will be 480, element[3] will be 100*" the read file line by line and split each line on space. Each of these steps is already explained at Stack Overflow or other sites.

Comment: Look at the `Scanner` class. A scanner allows you to read a file/string piece by piece by using `hasNext()`, `next()` and `readLine()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi In this case if you are not sure about the size of the array we can take advantage of ArrayList,Please look at the below code where I am trying to read the line separated by space and adding to the arraylist. You can also use the array as well.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdvanceCollection {
    static List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            File file = new File("path of your file");

            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                // here we are getting the full line
                String s[] = input.nextLine().split(" ");
                for (String text : s) {
                    arr.add(text);

                }

            }
            input.close();
            // here you can get the value by get method
            System.out.println(arr.get(0));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: PERFECT! thanks a lot man!